# Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 6 in .../tag.php on line 8

Tags: php, mysql, caching

i m using  php script which is used for watching videos.Last 2-3 days about i have  1k online people at same time and now i m getting internal server error at random times.When my site was getting lower number of visitor i have never seen this error.

```
<?php
include('config.php');
if($site[cache]>=3)
include('cache.head.php');
$tsef=htmlspecialchars($_GET[sef]);
$query=mysql_query("SELECT tag FROM tags WHERE sef='$tsef' LIMIT 1");
@mysql_query("UPDATE tags SET views=views+1 WHERE sef='$tsef'");
**$tag=mysql_result($query,0);**
$tkeywords=explode(' ',$tag);
?>
```

I think i need some caching mechanism as i see process limit is near maximum on my web hosting service.But i dont know hot wo implement.

Comment: You are wide open for [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d... `htmlspecialchars()` is **NOT** a defense.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that your query did not return any rows; you can't read a column out of nothing. There were no tags matching the "sef" value in the URL. I don't think it's related to your server load issues.

Let's clean this up a bit:

```
include('config.php');
if ($site[cache] >= 3)
    include('cache.head.php');

$tsef = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_GET['sef']));
$result = mysql_query("SELECT tag FROM tags WHERE sef='$tsef' LIMIT 1");

$tkeywords = array();
if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $tag = msyql_result($result, 0);
    $tkeywords = explode(' ', $tag);
    mysql_query("UPDATE tags SET views=views+1 WHERE sef='$tsef'"); 
}
```